# Scrollnav.js SideBar Won't Activate

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

Thank you for any help, and forgive me for being a noob.  The answer may very well be very simple;

I am trying to use a JQuery plugin called "[ScrollNav.js](http://scrollnav.com/)" for my personal site "EthanGreenspan.com".

I want to use this plugin to make a simple left pane with an interactive table of contents that lets users click sections to scroll to them.  As you can see in the JSFiddle (link at bottom), the  in the left pane does not function like the ScrollNav site.

This is the HTML for the  that I wish to use as the table of contents.

```
<div class="leftpane" class="main" role="main">
<nav class="scroll-nav" role="navigation">
<span class="scroll-nav-heading">Sections</span>
<ol class="scroll-nav-list">
<li class="scroll-nav-item active top">
<a href="#jumpNav-0" class="scroll-nav-link">Top</a></li>
<li class="scroll-nav-item active Current Work">
<a href="#jumpNav-1" class="scroll-nav-link"></a>Current Work</li>
<li>Photography</li>
<li>Consulting</li>
<li>Blog</li>
<li>Contact Me</li>
</ol>
```

This is the Jquery (I put it inline for JSFiddle)

```
<script>
$('.body').scrollNav({
    sections: 'h3',
    titletext: 'Scroll To',
    fixedmargin: 40,
    animation: true,
})

</script>
```

Finally, here is the ScrollNav JQuery plug-in;

```
(function(e){e.fn.scrollNav=function(t){e("body").addClass("sn-loading");var n={sections:"h3",titleText:"Scroll To",fixedMargin:40,animated:!0,speed:500,showHeadline:!0,showTopLink:!0,location:"insertBefore"};e.extend(n,t);var r=[],i=this,s=i.find(n.sections),o=e("<nav />",{"class":"scroll-nav",role:"navigation"}),u=function(){if(n.showTopLink===!1)return;var e=i.attr("id"),t=i.offset().top;if(e)r.push({id:e,offset:t,text:"Top"});else{i.attr("id","jumpNav-0");r.push({id:"jumpNav-0",offset:t,text:"Top"})}},a=function(){s.each(function(t){var n="jumpNav-"+(t+1),i=e(this).offset().top,s=e(this).text();e(this).attr("id",n);r.push({id:n,offset:i,text:s})})},f=function(){var t=e("<span />",{"class":"scroll-nav-heading",text:n.titleText}),i=e("<ol />",{"class":"scroll-nav-list"});e.each(r,function(t){var n=t===0?e("<li />",{"class":"scroll-nav-item active"}):e("<li />",{"class":"scroll-nav-item"}),r=e("<a />",{href:"#"+this.id,"class":"scroll-nav-link",text:this.text});i.append(n.append(r))});n.showHeadline===!0?o.append(t).append(i):o.append(i)},l=function(){var t=o.offset().top;e(window).resize(function(){e.each(r,function(){this.offset=e("#"+this.id).offset().top})});e(window).scroll(function(){var i=e(window).scrollTop(),s=e(window).height()*.5;i>t-n.fixedMargin?o.addClass("fixed"):o.removeClass("fixed");e.each(r,function(){if(this.offset>i-n.fixedMargin&&this.offset<i+s){o.find("li").removeClass("active");o.find('a[href="#'+this.id+'"]').parents("li").addClass("active")}})})};if(i.length!==0){u();a();f()}i.length!==0&&s.length!==0?o[n.location](i):i.length===0?console.log("Build failed, scrollNav could not find '"+i.selector+"'"):s.length===0&&console.log("Build failed, scrollNav could not find any '"+n.sections+"'s inside of '"+i.selector+"'");l();n.animated===!0&&e(".scroll-nav-link").click(function(){var t=e(this).attr("href"),r=e(t).offset().top;e("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({scrollTop:r-40},n.speed);return!1});e("body").removeClass("sn-loading").addClass("sn-active")}})(jQuery);
```

I understand the basics of JQuery, but could really use some help from you!

Here is a link to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EthanMax/DP7sf/) with my HTML/CSS/JS.

PLEASE AND THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Jimmy, author of the scrollNav.js jQuery plugin. The issue you're having is due to you creating the navigation items yourself. With scrollNav, you don't need to do this. The plugin scans your content and creates the nav items on it's own.

I forked your fiddle and reworked the markup to what scrollNav is looking for [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jimmynotjim/dtcWw/). I just released v2 of the plugin last week, so you'll want to make sure to update your own source before using my example code. The latest version allows you to pick the insertion point as well as each section's wrapping element, and you'll see I've defined those for you.

```
$('.post-article').scrollNav({
    sections: 'h3',
    sectionElem: 'div',
    insertTarget: '.leftpane',
    insertLocation: 'appendTo'
});
```

Be sure to read the [change log](https://github.com/jimmynotjim/scrollNav/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to see what else has changed in the new release.

Comment: Hi Jimmy! As a coding and StackOverflow noob, it's really great to get a note from the author of ScrollNav.js.  Firstly, congrats on making a really cool plugin; it inspired me to start the side project I referenced above.  Some work has since taken most of my time, but I appreciate the help and I will be sure to take your advice when I am able to get back into coding again.  Thanks again, resident noob.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your anchors are closed properly. And that you've included jQuery then the Scroll script after it in the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/DP7sf/5/

**Order of scripts**

```
<script src="/linktojQuery.js"></script>
<script src="/linktoScrollNav.js"></script>

<script>
// Document.ready function here
</script>
```

**Correct link format**

```
<li><a href="#jumpNav-0" class="scroll-nav-link">Top</a></li>
<li class="scroll-nav-item active Current Work"><a href="#jumpNav-1" class="scroll-nav-link">Current Work</a></li>
<li><a href="#jumpNav-2" class="scroll-nav-link">Photography</a></li>
```

Wrap your jQuery plugin call with a [document.ready function](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) so it only loads after the DOM is loaded.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.body').scrollNav({
    sections: 'h3',
    titletext: 'Scroll To',
    fixedmargin: 40,
    animation: true
   });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed!  Question Part II

I'd like to manipulate the scrollTop offset with a percentage instead of the current code which is;

"scrollTop:r-26" within JQuery.scrollNav.min.js.